# How to cancel a call using VoIP

Tags: ios, swift, voip, xcode11, callkit

Now, after `Xcode11 / iOS13`, Apple forces developers to report a new incoming call when they receive a VoIP signal otherwise the app will be terminated.

**So, any idea what should I do in case I need to cancel the call?**

For example, the caller terminates the call and I want the receiver to stop ringing?

I found the following workaround by Twillo to display the calling screen and quickly hide it but it lasts for 3-3 seconds which is a bad UX in my POV.

```
// iOS 13 workaround
let uuid = UUID()
reportIncomingCall(from: "Voice Bot", uuid: uuid)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performEndCallAction(uuid: self.callInvite!.uuid)
}
```

Comment: If you receive a call, it's correct to display the incoming call UI even if the caller cancels the call afterward, isn't it?